# Package, triggers and procedure not working as they should

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, procedure

I need some help guys because I don't see where is the problem with this code.

I have 2 tables. Products(id,..,currentPrice) and Prices(id, product_id, date, price). I need to create triggers and procedures that will automaticlly update values in Products.currentPrice when value in Prices.price is inserted, updated or deleted. 
I createad a package, two triggers and a procedure and they all compile OK but when I insert, update or delete a value nothing happens.
But when I manually call procedure and insert product_id (for example value 1 for existing product in Products table) value in Products.currentPrice for product with id 1 is updated every time.
I guess that value from BEFORE trigger is not saved in the PACKAGE variable because i get 'no data found' error. 
I am using SQL Developer and Oracle 11g XE.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage IS
gid NUMBER;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_currentprice1
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON prices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (INSERTING OR UPDATING) THEN
    BEGIN
      mypackage.gid := :new.product_id;
    END;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      mypackage.gid := :old.product_id;
    END;
  END IF;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_currentprice2
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON prices
DECLARE
  v_id NUMBER := mypackage.gid;  
BEGIN
    calc_currentprice(v_id);
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calc_currentprice(prodid IN NUMBER) AS
  curprice Products.currentPrice%TYPE;
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  curprice := 0;
SELECT price INTO curprice FROM prices
WHERE product_id = prodid AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM prices WHERE product_id = prodid AND date <= SYSDATE);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER trg_products_forbid2 DISABLE';
UPDATE products
SET currentPrice = curprice
WHERE product_id = prodid;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER trg_products_forbid2 ENABLE';
END;
```

Comment: Agreed with unleashed - you shouldn't be using an autonomous transaction, nor should you be altering the trigger here. One of the many reasons why not include the fact that altering a trigger is a global operation and affects all sessions, not just the current session.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a couple of things here that are concerning.  First, you are trying to use two triggers to perform a sequence of work.  Order of the triggers firing will not be guaranteed.  Consider the following in one trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_currentprice1
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON prices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (INSERTING OR UPDATING) THEN
    BEGIN
      calc_currentprice(:new.product_id);
    END;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      calc_currentprice(:old.product_id);
    END;
  END IF;
END;
```

Second, in your proc, you specify an autonomous transaction, but you don't commit.

Now, these help your code, but there are some other things you should know.

I would recommend not running this with triggers.  If you have PL/SQL code to update the prices, then include code to also update the products.  Maybe better yet, can you disassociate the price from the product such that you don't have to update the product record at all and just look up the current price for the product on demand as needed.

Don't include commits within trigger processing like this.  If the users transaction does not commit, then you are committing a change within that will no longer be valid, but will remain, so you have the possibility of updating the product with a price that does not exist after a rollback.

Don't disable/enable triggers within your code.  If you have to do this, then your design is flawed.

You are trying to use a global variable across execution of code.  This also should be avoided.

Comment: I am new to PL/SQL and this code is one small part of bigger assignment that I have to do for learning purpose. I am required to use triggers and procedures. I have read what you have told me but because I am 'noob' with Oracle PL/SQL i didn't get it very well. If i get your words right I should add COMMIT; after second autonomous transaction...

Comment: Actually, you SHOULD remove PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION from that proc and only commit your transaction as a normal transaction, in one of your other outer procs or proc calls.

Comment: But if remove PRAGMA then I can't update currentPrice field in Products because I have mandatory trigger which forbid changing that value. I can move PRAGMA inside AFTER trigger which will call this procedure. But as I sad, procedure on her own works but in combination with package and 2 trigger it does not and I can see a solution.

Comment: Aha!  Because DDL will cause a commit.  But, what is very unclear.  You want to update a value for which you have a trigger that is supposed to keep you from updating said value.  You have diametrically opposed requirements.  Also, as I mentioned before, you don't want a commit to happen within your trigger in real world code because the outer transaction may be rolled back.